# PowerShell Forms Won't Trigger DragDrop

Tags: winforms, powershell, powershell-4.0

There's nothing to suggest that a simple Windows Forms DragDrop won't work in PowerShell, and several resources explaining that it does work, however I cannot get any of them working. Even something as simple as this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$TBcode = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$form.Controls.Add($TBcode)

$TBcode.Dock = "Fill"
$TBcode.Multiline = $true
$TBCode.ScrollBars = "Vertical"
$TBCode.AllowDrop = $true
$TBcode.Add_DragEnter({ Write-Host "DragEnter"; $_.Effects = "Copy" })
$TBcode.Add_DragDrop({ Write-Host "DragDrop" })
$TBcode.Add_MouseEnter({ Write-Host "Mouse Enter" })

$form.ShowDialog()
```

The MouseEnter event triggers normally however when attempting to drag anything in to the TextBox nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a sudden realisation and was able to confirm that this is in fact User Account Control.

Because I'm on Windows 10 I've got my PowerShell running as Administrator so I can actually do what I need to, however an object from the User-level Explorer process (or anything else running as a user) will simply refuse to interact with the Administrator-level PowerShell form.

Running PowerShell as a user allows the DragDrop to work as expected, but good luck if you need it to be admin! >_>